# Hilbert curves: bounds / probabilities of preserving neighbors

Tags: probability, spatial, distance, curves

[Hilbert Curves (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) are space-filling curves said to "fairly well preserve locality".

Do you know any *theoretical* results here, such as bounds that neighbors within a radius of $\varepsilon$ are preserved with probability $p$ or anything like that? Wikipedia also only has a "citation needed" flag there.

I'd like to be able to give probabilistic bounds on the error when using Hilbert curves, for nearest neighbor search in $d$ dimensions on clustered data (i.e. not uniform on the data space). I believe I saw some results for $d=2$, but I'm interested in the more general case.

Thank you for references to theoretical work on the quality of the hilbert curve.

Comment: In order for this question to be answerable, Erich, please tell us *how* you intend to "use" Hilbert curves and what probability model you are adopting.

Comment: Updated, I'm interested in nearest neighbor search by using the order produced by the curve. I'm not sure what you refer to by probability model. Plus, I'm not looking for a single equation, but for references that then may well give details on their assumptions. Some that I already found are: Hungershöfer and Wierum 2002; Gotsman and Lindenbaum 1996; Moon, Jagadish et al 2001.

Comment: Unless you make explicit *probabilistic* assumptions about the possible positions of the neighbors, it is not possible to give "probabilistic bounds" (it doesn't even make sense to do so).  Please edit your question to make it clear to readers that you are interested in neighborhood search and, if you can, state your assumptions about the positions of the neighbors.

Comment: Whatever probabilistic assumptions there exist *results* for. I do not have any assumptions except "the data is not uniform". I added the "nearest neighbor search" 1 hour ago already.